# Big-O Runtime for filtering an NSArray using NSpredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, big-o, nspredicate

what is the approximate big-O runtime for using an NSPredicate to filter an array? I can't seem to find anything about predicate runtimes.  Thanks

Comment: I dont understand the down votes. This is a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Big-O for filtering an NSArray using NSPredicate **will be O(n).**

Comment: Is that per predicate?  If you compound to five prdeicates for example?

Comment: Predicate for array will go on to traverse each one, for dictionary it will be faster. And for 5 predicates, it be be 5 times.

Comment: e.g. PFBatchFaultingArray's runtime may differ

Comment: [(NS|CF)Arrays are not necessarily what they seem to be.](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html)

Comment: I don't see why predicate filtering a dictionary would be any faster than filtering an array. Predicate filtering is not a key lookup; you'd still have to look at every element.

Comment: @PeterHosey: I was expecting NSPredicate to use the hash map to search... Thanks for Sharing this information. :)